# How to change UIToolbar button icons to hi-res on a Universal app if the device supports retina display?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, universal-binary

I am working on a Universal app, there is a UIToolbar with the 20x20px icon as images, but I need to switch this to their hi-res counterpart (40x40px) if the device supports retina display, any tips how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the high-res icons with "@2x" and they will automatically be used.